# Model groups of variables and their interactions separately

Tags: probability, copula

I want to decompose a multivariate pdf $p(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, where each $x_i$ is a collection of one or more random variables, into its "marginals" $p(x_1), p(x_2), p(x_3)$:

$p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = p(x_1)p(x_2)p(x_3) \cdot Z$

The goal is to be able to model interactions within the groups and between the groups separately, since I have different amounts of data for each group and only limited data that contains all groups for learning dependencies.

Intuitively I thought I could apply copula theory to determine an expression for the missing $Z$ that describes the dependencies between the groups of variables, but it seems that they are defined for univariate marginals.

Is there any extension of copula theory where the "margins" are groups of vairables, or some probability theory in general, to describe $Z$ apart from simply setting

$Z = \frac{p(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{p(x_1)p(x_2)p(x_3)}$ ?

Can $Z$ be expressed as some probability distribution over all variables?

Comment: This looks nothing like a copula, and also has nothing to do with "multivariate marginals" either. Your question title is not helpful. The copula looks like $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=c(F(x_1),F(x_2),F(x_3))$, where $F(.)$ is a CDF and $f()$ is PDF. you seem to be looking for some sort of separability

Comment: Edited my post. I thought there might be a way, similar to copulas using $F$, to project each group of variables (random vector) with some function so that they are uniformly distributed in some interval (to eliminate inter-group interactions and marginal structure). Then one could combine these spaces and model a probability distribution in it, which is the missing $Z$

Comment: I doubt its possible

Comment: What if I apply Gaussianization to each group of variables separately (let's say there's three variables in each group), and then transform each of them to be uniformly distributed in a unit hypercube ($[0,1]^d$), where all intra-group structure has been removed.
Then I combine these hypercube spaces to form one probability distribution (with support over $[0,1]^{3d}$) where the only structure (non-uniformity) is arising because of inter-group correlations, which could be the $Z$ I am searching for

Comment: Go ahead, and do it. Nobody's preventing you from doing this. If the result is good, put a paper in arxiv and share with a world

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**
In the example you stated above, your definition of $Z$ is the copula density function, $c$, of the copula function, $C$, which defines the dependence structure between the random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$.

**Detailed answer**

Sklar's theorem is often expressed 
$$C(F_1(x_1),F_2(x_2),\dots, F_n(x_n)) = H(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$, where $X_i$, are continuous random variables and $H$ is the joint distribution function of the random variables.  If we define $U_i = F_i(X_i)$, then we can rewrite Sklar's theorem as:

$$C(u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n) = H(F^{-1}_1(X_1), F^{-1}_2(X_2),\dots, F^{-1}_n(X_n))$$

Because $C$ is a proper distribution function in its own right, it has an associated density (called the copula density function), which we can derive by derivating along every dimension of the copula.  More specifically, we can write:

$$c(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n) = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial u_1 \partial u_2 \cdots \partial u_n} C(u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n) = \frac{f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)}{f(x_1)f(x_2)\cdots f(x_n)}$$

**Where to go from here?**

So, what you've laid out above in $Z$ is in fact exactly the copula density.  That being said, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but some common things to do are to model your desired dependency based on a copula of choice (either data driven or expert knowledge driven).  Suppose you have some univariate random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, and a desired dependence structure encapsulated by copula $C$.  Then, to generate samples of the desired multivariate distribution, you'd first sample $U_1$, $U_2$, and $U_3$ from $C$, and then apply $F^{-1}_i(u_i) = x_i$ to generate the samples from your joint distribution.

Sources:

- [Sklar's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar's_theorem)
- [Generating samples from copulas](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/simulating-dependent-random-variables-using-copulas.html)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Unfortunately a small but important detail was ignored here, which is that each $x_i$ is a collection of multiple random variables, so that $p(x_i)$ is a multivariate distribution, not a univariate one as apparently required in the copula framework.

Maybe copula theory does not apply and instead an extension can be found. Is [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X96900020) the extension I am looking for? Is anyone familiar with the possible restrictions (less convenient properties) compared to normal copulas?

Comment: @Kiran could you also answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485219/derivation-of-sklars-theorem-for-copula